# Problem creating a build archive for ios using flutter_secure_storage package

Tags: ios, flutter, package, storage, ipa

I'm trying to produce an archive (IPA file) of my application made with Flutter. I'm following the official guide for that: [Preparing an iOS app for release: Create a build archive](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive).

I have a problem producing the archive when I'm using the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) package.

When I try to produce the archive (Xcode -> Product -> Archive), I get the following error:

```sh
Runner: 1 issue
/Path/to/my/project/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: 
'flutter_secure_storage/FlutterSecureStoragePlugin.h' file not found
```

I can compile the project (from Xcode/Visual Code or using "flutter build ios --release" command) without any issue.  I only get the issue when I'm trying to generate the archive.

Do I need to change something in the project settings for creating the archive?

Comment: Did you install CocoaPods that come with the project? https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Comment: Yes. CocoaPods is installed.

Found the problem. I was trying to create the archive from the Runner.xcodeproj instead of the Runner.xcworkspace (which defines the pods targets). Switching to that project succeeded to produce the archive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to create the archive from the *Runner.xcodeproj* instead of the *Runner.xcworkspace* (which defines the pods targets).

Switching to that project solved the issue to produce the archive.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the platform: ios version is aligned with the one in the Podfile:

Version in `Target -> Runner -> General -> Deployment Info`
should be the same as the on in your Podfile.

Checkout this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6nPr.png

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that you're opening Runner.xcworkspace and not Runner.xcodeproj